# How to validate Tiny MCE Editor in frontend custom form and how to do for uploading image from my PC in TinyMCE Editor in Magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, tinymce, image-upload

I am able to show Tiny MCE Editor in my Magento Frontent custom form by the help of here [How to add wysiwyg editor to custom frontend form of custom module in Magento1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49504/how-to-add-wysiwyg-editor-to-custom-frontend-form-of-custom-module-in-magento1-9/49565?noredirect=1#comment67446_49565).But with magento default class "required-entry required-entry textarea", TinyMCE Editor is not validating. **How to validate this TinyMCE Editor in Magento frontend custom form**. And **I also want to upload image file from My PC that will be available in TinyMCE Editor**.Currently there is a text box of Image URL insertion in TinyMCE Editor. I need a browse besides "Image URL insertion textbox" by which it can be uploaded a image file from PC.